# Using parallel cookie sessions for a browser / Logging multiple users in at the same time

Tags: php, cookies, autohotkey

I often do the same tasks on multiple clients's accounts at a website I do not own, and I was wondering how can I use the database of username/password I have in tandem with parallel sessions of an external website to cut down time?

I'm familiar with php and autohotkey for windows, but also develop on the mac. Where would you guys head given this info to cut down the menial task-work?

Also, Sandboxie isn't my style. I'm not keen on coding an autohotkey to open so many browsers (upwards of 100 accts).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can <strike>emulate</strike> impersonate a browser in PHP with curl.

Try starting here:
http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php

It could be as easy as building a  form as a string and submit it with the headers, and then requesting a series of urls.

Chances are you need headers with cookies in and possibly special form tokens or other protection on the target site.  You're probably going to need to parse HTML, i think simpleHTMLdom is the tool.

Are the tasks you want to perform reasonably definable by code?  You can react to values that you know about. But keep in mind that a php solution will be headless, unless you program it to behave otherwise.

Some more relevant reading: http://www.phpcodester.com/2011/01/scraping-a-password-protected-website-with-curl/

Comment: The website I log into isn't mine. I can't manipulate multiple fields without the use of autohotkey. Think me logging into multiple gmail accts and editing an existing contact's information. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I do pretty much only clicking--following links, choosing an option out of a dropdown, and typing a value. If I can do this for multiple logins with curl, then you sir are amazing. Does headless mean sans GUI or sans directions?

Comment: Headless meaning without GUI or directions.  It's likely that when done, all you'll see is your print statements, which are updating you as to whether things happened as you expected.  Also, I've edited the answer with another link i think you will find useful.

Comment: thanks jon! i think i'll be able to get a good head start here, gave you the plus and check! :)